# Checkmarx: Second-Order SQL Injection attack in c#

Tags: c#, security, sql-injection, checkmarx

How would I satisfy the static code analysis tool (in this case checkmarx) that there are no issues with the following method:

```
public OdbcDataReader ExecuteQuery(string sql)
{
   var cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, connection);
   return cmd.ExecuteReader();
}
```

Checkmarx tells me the following:

> Method ExecuteQuery gets database data from the ExecuteReader element. 
>       This element’s value then flows through the code
>        without being properly sanitized or validated, and is eventually
>       used in a database query in method ExecuteQuery. 
>       This may enable an Second-Order SQL Injection attack.

Comment: Is there any kind of input sanitation done on 'sql' before it reaches your ExecuteQuery method? I am inferring the analysis tool is seeing 'sql' go in and then be passed into the constructor for the OdbcCommand object unchecked before ExecuteReader fires...

Comment: The SQL is hard coded on the web server side.  It uses String.Format in stead of parameters

Comment: Well, unfortunately, that's more or less Thing Not To Do 101 as far as SQL Injection (straight string rather than parameterized query) is concerned. Unless I'm misunderstanding the situation, could you not do at least some sanitation checks within this method?

Comment: @Robben_Ford_Fan_boy -- the tool is telling you not to use String.Format -- change to parameterized queries and the message will go away.  Of you could sanitize the inputs to string format -- *which is much harder*

Answer (score 1):

Doing this satisfied CheckMarx:

```
public OdbcDataReader ExecuteQuery(string sql)
{
    var cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql.Replace("'", ""), connection);
    return cmd.ExecuteReader();
}
```

Interestingly, I scanned the method on its own, and using a command did not satisfy it:

```
public OdbcDataReader ExecuteQuery(string sql)
    {
        OdbcCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        return cmd.ExecuteReader();
    }
```

Comment: Note that you're just hiding the problem, your code is still likely to be vulnerable to a smart attacker (it's just harder for the tool to give you unambiguous results with a high degree of certainty. Look for results from other queries, with lower "risk").

Comment: Also, simply separating the sql from the command constructor does not do anything different. Why would you expect it to? Instead, you should be using stored procedures (instead of hardcoded SQL query strings), and create the command as such by setting the `CommandType` to `StoredProcedure`.

Comment: The fix,  var cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql.Replace("'", ""), connection); , worked for me as well. Many thanks